# How to get a status progress when cloning a repo via nodegit?

Tags: typescript, nodegit

I use [Clone.clone](https://www.nodegit.org/api/clone/) from `nodegit` and I am looking for a progress status callback. The function has a [CheckoutOptions](https://www.nodegit.org/api/checkout_options/) object, which I call like this:

```
var opts: CloneOptions = {};
opts.checkoutOpts = {
    progressCb: function() {
        console.log("Foo");
    },
}
```

But that seems to crash the BrowserWindow. Does anyone, by looking at the declaration of `CheckoutOptions` what I might do wrong?

**Notice, `CheckoutOptions` is a member of `CloneOptions`**

```
export class CheckoutOptions {
    version?: number;
    checkoutStrategy?: number;
    disableFilters?: number;
    dirMode?: number;
    fileMode?: number;
    fileOpenFlags?: number;
    notifyFlags?: number;
    notifyCb?: any;
    notifyPayload?: undefined;
    progressCb?: any;
    progressPayload?: undefined;
    paths?: Strarray | string | string[];
    baseline?: Tree;
    baselineIndex?: Index;
    targetDirectory?: string;
    ancestorLabel?: string;
    ourLabel?: string;
    theirLabel?: string;
    perfdataCb?: any;
    perfdataPayload?: undefined;
    [key: string]: any;
}

export class CloneOptions {
    version?: number;
    checkoutOpts?: CheckoutOptions;
    fetchOpts?: FetchOptions;
    bare?: number;
    local?: number;
    checkoutBranch?: string;
    repositoryCbPayload?: any;
    remoteCbPayload?: any;
}
```

Comment: have you checked out progressCb in CheckoutOptions

Comment: Yes, see my first code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing the checkout options using `new CheckoutOptions()` instead of using just an empty object `{}`.

This version works:

```
var opts = {};
opts.checkoutOpts = new CheckoutOptions();
opts.checkoutOpts.progressCb = function(){
    console.log("Foo");
};
```

and this version crashes:

```
var opts = {};
opts.checkoutOpts = {};
opts.checkoutOpts.progressCb = function(){
    console.log("Foo");
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Although the callback is actually not called many times during the clone procedure, it works for me. I will add the +150 points once I am allowed to accept it